# Unity UI Inputfiled can't type Chinese in IOS by Speed Dial type

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

1. Create an UI InputField component, and choose the linetype to Singleline.
2. Build the game and install it to an IOS device(ex. iPhone).
3. Set the keyboard to Speed Dial type and Chinese pinyin input.
4. Open the game, and you can't type Chinese characters into the inputfield.
   But other kind keyboard works fine.

Anybody can tell me why?

My unity version is 5.3.4f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a bug with 5.3.x* versions. It use to happen with Japanese keyboards but I had no idea it happens to Chinese keyboards too. **Unity 5.4** fixed this issue with Japanese keyboards and I think that the issue was also fixed for Chinese inputs too.  Upgrading to 5.4 version seems to be the only way to fix this problem.

Just in-case you want to know which bug number this is, it is a `791387` bug number on this [site](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/unity5.4.0f2).